# How to call props of a sidebar Component? - Leads to TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am adding a props of sidebar Component to my template.

I am passing  {...this.props} to Sidebar. 
But it still leads to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in my Menu file.`

My `PostTemplateDetails` file that I wish to add the Sidebar component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import moment from 'moment'
import './style.scss'

class PostTemplateDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { subtitle, author } = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata
    const post = this.props.data.markdownRemark
    const tags = post.fields.tagSlugs

    const tagsBlock = (
      <div className="post-single__tags">
        <ul className="post-single__tags-list">
          {tags &&
            tags.map((tag, i) => (
              <li className="post-single__tags-list-item" key={tag}>
                <Link to={tag} className="post-single__tags-list-item-link">
                  {post.frontmatter.tags[i]}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar {...this.props} />
        <div className="content">
  <div className="content__inner">
        <div className="post-single">
          <div className="post-single__inner">
            <h1 className="post-single__title">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <div
              className="post-single__body"
              /* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger */
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }}
            />
            <div className="post-single__date">
              <em>
                Published {moment(post.frontmatter.date).format('D MMM YYYY')}
              </em>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="post-single__footer">
            {tagsBlock}
            <hr />
            <p className="post-single__footer-text">
              {subtitle}
              <a
                href={`https://twitter.com/${author.twitter}`}
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                <br /> <strong>{author.name}</strong> on Twitter
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>


    )
  }
}

export default PostTemplateDetails
```

My Sidebar component file:

```
import React from 'react'
import get from 'lodash/get'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import Menu from '../Menu'
import Links from '../Links'
import profilePic from '../../pages/photo.jpg'
import './style.scss'

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props
    const {
      author,
      subtitle,
      copyright,
      menu,
    } = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata
    const isHomePage = get(location, 'pathname', '/') === '/'

    /* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt */
    const authorBlock = (
      <div>
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            src={profilePic}
            className="sidebar__author-photo"
            width="75"
            height="75"
            alt={author.name}
          />
        </Link>
        {isHomePage ? (
          <h1 className="sidebar__author-title">
            <Link className="sidebar__author-title-link" to="/">
              {author.name}
            </Link>
          </h1>
        ) : (
          <h2 className="sidebar__author-title">
            <Link className="sidebar__author-title-link" to="/">
              {author.name}
            </Link>
          </h2>
        )}
        <p className="sidebar__author-subtitle">{subtitle}</p>
      </div>
    )
    /* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt */

    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar__inner">
          <div className="sidebar__author">{authorBlock}</div>
          <div>
            <Menu data={menu} />
            <Links data={author} />
            <p className="sidebar__copyright">{copyright}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

My Menu component file, which is added in the Sidebar component file - this is where the error seems to be residing.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import './style.scss'

class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const menu = this.props.data

    const menuBlock = (
      <ul className="menu__list">
        {menu.map(item => (
          <li className="menu__list-item" key={item.path}>
            <Link
              to={item.path}
              className="menu__list-item-link"
              activeClassName="menu__list-item-link menu__list-item-link--active"
            >
              {item.label}
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )

    return <nav className="menu">{menuBlock}</nav>
  }
}

export default Menu
```

I am not sure why this is not working, since adding  in my `PAGETemplateDetails` file seem to be working fine:

```
import React from 'react'
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar'
import './style.scss'

class PageTemplateDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const page = this.props.data.markdownRemark

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar {...this.props} />
        <div className="content">
          <div className="content__inner">
            <div className="page">
              <h1 className="page__title">{page.frontmatter.title}</h1>
              <div
                className="page__body"
                /* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger */
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.html }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PageTemplateDetails
```

SiteMetadata.menu is queried on the Post template File:

```
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import PostTemplateDetails from '../components/PostTemplateDetails'

class PostTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { title, subtitle } = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata
    const post = this.props.data.markdownRemark
    const { title: postTitle, description: postDescription } = post.frontmatter
    const description = postDescription !== null ? postDescription : subtitle

    return (
      <Layout>
        <div>
          <Helmet>
            <title>{`${postTitle} - ${title}`}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={description} />
          </Helmet>
          <PostTemplateDetails {...this.props} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default PostTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        subtitle
        copyright
        author {
          name
          twitter
        }
        disqusShortname
        url
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      id
      html
      fields {
        tagSlugs
      }
      frontmatter {
        title
        tags
        date
        description
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Not sure if this is relevant but this is the post file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import moment from 'moment'
import './style.scss'

class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      title,
      date,
      category,
      description,
    } = this.props.data.node.frontmatter
    const { slug, categorySlug } = this.props.data.node.fields

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <div className="post__meta">
          <time
            className="post__meta-time"
            dateTime={moment(date).format('MMMM D, YYYY')}
          >
            {moment(date).format('MMMM YYYY')}
          </time>
          <span className="post__meta-divider" />
          <span className="post__meta-category" key={categorySlug}>
            <Link to={categorySlug} className="post__meta-category-link">
              {category}
            </Link>
          </span>
        </div>
        <h2 className="post__title">
          <Link className="post__title-link" to={slug}>
            {title}
          </Link>
        </h2>
        <p className="post__description">{description}</p>
        <Link className="post__readmore" to={slug}>
          Read
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Post
```

Comment: Can your share with us your Menu component? It appears you left that out and ended up pasting Sidebar twice.

Comment: Edited! Thank you!

Comment: Where exactly do you query for siteMetadata.menu?

Comment: I believe it is queried in the Post Template File, I uploaded it

Comment: console.log(menu) what give you back?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the property `data` as "menu" `<Menu data={menu} />`

In the Menu component, you don't have the `menu` property, you have `this.props.data`, which is equal to `menu` value, as defined in the Sidebar component. Probably there's no such property "menu" on `this.props.data`

So your code should be `const data = this.props` or `const menu = this.props.data` if you want to keep the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, it was a query problem as ksav suspected. The Menu and Sidebar components were fine. I failed to query the menu information in my sitemetadata, and was able to fix it by going to my Post Template File and querying the menu, like so:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
        subtitle
        copyright
        menu {
          label
          path
        }
        author {
          name
          twitter
        }
        disqusShortname
        url
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      id
      html
      fields {
        tagSlugs
      }
      frontmatter {
        title
        tags
        date
        description
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Thank you everyone, I'm struggling but I got there.